# React Navigation(V3):How to set navigation function in custom router file?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a `Router.js` to set all of my components with react-navigation.

When I click the component `FloorScreen` `headerRight` button will show click alert.

Now I want to change it like `this.props.navigation.navigate.goBack();`

Router.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// and import some screen...

    const Router = createStackNavigator({
      WelcomeScreen: {
        screen: WelcomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          header: null
        }),
      },
      HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen
      },
      FloorScreen: {
        screen: FloorScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'test',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: commonColor.appBackgroundColor,
          },
          headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('click')}>
            <Image style={{ width: 20, height: 20}} source={BackIcon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'WelcomeScreen',
      headerMode: 'screen'
    });

    export default createAppContainer(Router);
```

I know I can set the code in FloorScreen.js to achieve it:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerRight : (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>  
               <Image />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    });
```

Is possible to set the code in my Router.js ? Or set the code in FloorScreen.js is the only way to do it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it at `navigationOption`

```
navigationOptions: () => ({
              tabBarLabel: strings.labelJobs,
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="someName" />
              ),
              tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
                if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
                  navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
                }
                defaultHandler();
              }
            })
```

The above is to demonstrate how to display first screen of stack, just to show you how you can access `navigation` within `navigationOptions`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I do not think I have this.props.navigation elements in my Router.js.

Comment: Yes you do, just use `navigation.goBack()` which is essentially the same thing